# Using for loop on arrays

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, primes

I should compute the roots and squares of prime numbers given in an array.

The results should both be stored in two new arrays. My solution was:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.lang.Math;

public class Array1 {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] primeNumbers = {3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17};
        for (int i = 0; i < primeNumbers.length-1; i++) {
            double[] root = new double[primeNumbers.length-1];
            root[i] = Math.sqrt(primeNumbers[i]);
            if ( i == primeNumbers.length-2 ) {
                System.out.println( Arrays.toString( root ));
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < primeNumbers.length-1; i++) {
            double[] square = new double[primeNumbers.length-1];
            square[i] = primeNumbers[i] * primeNumbers[i];
            if ( i == primeNumbers.length-2 ) {
                System.out.println( Arrays.toString( square ));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunatelly, the result of my solution is:

```
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.605551275463989]

[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 169.0]
```

Please help me here.

Comment: When asking questions related to code, you should add a tag to the question indicating what programming language the code is in.

Comment: `double[] root = new double[primeNumbers.length-1];` you create a new array on every iteration. Maybe that's your problem. Please take the [tour], go through the [help], read [ask], try to learn how to use a debugger as well

Comment: Are you required to store the squares and roots in arrays, or just print them out? Also, why are you only printing for i==primeNumbers.length-2?

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring the output arrays inside the for loops. Try declaring them outside of the for loop like so:

```
double[] root = new double[primeNumbers.length-1];
for (int i = 0; i < primeNumbers.length-1; i++) {

    root[i] = Math.sqrt(primeNumbers[i]);
    if ( i == primeNumbers.length-2 ) {
        System.out.println( Arrays.toString( root ));
    }
}
double[] square = new double[primeNumbers.length-1];
for (int i = 0; i < primeNumbers.length-1; i++) {

    square[i] = primeNumbers[i] * primeNumbers[i];
    if ( i == primeNumbers.length-2 ) {
        System.out.println( Arrays.toString( square ));
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are we ignoring the last element of the array (I know that's what the OP does, but your solution does that too).

Comment: I guess I'm not sure why OP did that. I agree that it is odd.